# how to read every ten lines of file using awk in loop?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file in which lines are separated using a "return". I want to use two loops, one loop for reading every ten lines and one loop for doing a specific operation on those specific ten lines. How to read each ten lines in the file using awk?

The sample file is this:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
9 10
7 8
6 5
4 3
2 1
2 1
4 3
5 4
6 5
7 6
8 7
9 8
0 9
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
9 10
7 8
6 5
4 3
2 1
2 1
4 3
5 4
6 5
7 6
8 7
9 8
0 9
```

I want to read each ten lines, then print the average of both numbers in those ten lines and print.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs and outputs

Comment: I have added the sample inputs.

Comment: Not for the 10th line, but I want to take each ten lines from the file and then print the average for those ten lines. Thus displaying the average for each ten lines separately.

Comment: For example the first ten lines include the following numbers: 1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
9 10
7 8
6 5
4 3
2 1, I want their average. Then the next ten lines include these numbers: 2 1
4 3
5 4
6 5
7 6
8 7
9 8
0 9
1 2
3 4, I want to print their average.

Comment: Can you shrink your example to two or three, instead of 10?

Comment: Right, we don't need to see 50 or so lines of input to understand the problem and PLEASE provide the expected output so we're not guessing at what you mean/want. And why are you asking for loops? That's HOW to do something and it may not be the best approach to geeat WHAT you want (which still isn't clear).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    {sum1 += $1; sum2 += $2} 
    function output() {print sum1/10, sum2/10; sum1 = sum2 = 0} 
    NR % 10 == 0 {output()} 
    END {output()}
' input.file
```

outputs

```
5.3 5.7
4.5 4.9
5.5 5.5
3.5 3.9
```

The END only has 6 lines of data, but is dividing by 10. Please make your requirements more precise.

Comment: I think you need to check if `output()` was just called before calling it again in the END section to avoid duplicate output of the last values when the number of lines in the file is a multiple of 10. +1 though.

Comment: isn't there a way to avoid declaring the function every time?

Comment: @fedorqui, I don't understand your comment. the function will only be declared once.

Comment: What I mean is that you can move the definition of the function outside the main block and give parameters. Dummy example: `awk 'function r(d) {print d+1}  BEGIN {print "we start"} r($1)'` instead of `awk 'BEGIN {print "we start"} function r(d) {print d+1}  r($1)'`

Comment: awk doesn't have a "main block": ["Definitions of functions can appear anywhere between the rules of an awk program."](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Definition-Syntax.html#Definition-Syntax).  Your examples are identical.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to check a counter and output and reset the current sum per column if the counter reaches a multiple of 10.  Note that this will swallow the last few records if the total number of lines is not a multiple of 10.  If you are sure your file won't contain any blank lines, the code can be further simplified.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    chunk_size = 10;
    sum_first = 0;
    sum_second = 0;
    record_counter = 0;
}

/[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+/ {
    record_counter += 1;
    sum_first += $1;
    sum_second += $2;
    if (record_counter % chunk_size == 0) {
        printf("%16.9f %16.9f\n",
               sum_first / chunk_size,
               sum_second / chunk_size);
        sum_first = 0;
        sum_second = 0;
    }
}
```

Output for your example data:

```
     5.300000000      5.700000000
     4.500000000      4.900000000
     5.500000000      5.500000000
```

Answer (score 0):

As nu11po1n7er(sorry if i mispelled your name) has removed their answer i am going to add a similar one

```
awk -vc="10" '{a+=$1+$2}!(--c){c=10;print a/c;a=0}END{if(c)print a/(10-c)}' file
```

#### output

```
11
9.4
11
12.3333
```

This will print the average of every ten lines field one and two added together(which is what i gathered from OPs post/comments).
If it finished not on a multiple of 10 it will divide by however many lines were left for the avg.

Answer (score 0):

situation1: only print one ave of per 10 line.

```
awk 'NR%10!=0{tmp=tmp+$1+ $2}NR%10==0{tmp = tmp+ $1+$2; print tmp/20; tmp=0}' 1.t
```

output:

```
5.5
4.7
5.5
```

situation2: print two averages for each column of per 10 line.

```
awk 'NR%10!=0{tmp=tmp+$1; tmp2=tmp2+$2}NR%10==0{tmp = tmp+ $1; tmp2=tmp2+$2; print tmp/10, tmp2/10; tmp=tmp2=0}' 1.t
```

output:

```
5.3 5.7
4.5 4.9
5.5 5.5
```

Comment: first one `awk '{tmp=tmp+$1+ $2}NR%10==0{print tmp/20; tmp=0}'`

Comment: second one `awk '{tmp=tmp+$1; tmp2=tmp2+$2}NR%10==0{print tmp/10, tmp2/10; tmp=tmp2=0}'`

Comment: @Jidder, smart!  `tmp += $1 + $2` instead of `tmp=tmp+$1 +$2` ref @glenn. The Precedence of `+` is higher than that of `+=`.

Comment: yea should have spotted that, just wanted to show there was a lot of redundant code :)