# Take mean of columns in text file by every 10-row blocks in bash

Tags: bash

I have a tab delimited text file with two columns without header. Now, I want to take the mean of each column within blocks of 10 rows. This means, I take the first 10 rows, take the mean between the 10 numbers in each column and output the mean of each column into another text file. Now go further, take the next 10 rows and make the same again. Until the end of the file. If there are less than 10 rows left at the end, just take the mean of the left rows.

Input file:

```
0.32832977  3.50941E-10
0.31647876  3.38274E-10
0.31482627  3.36508E-10
0.31447645  3.36134E-10
0.31447645  3.36134E-10
0.31396809  3.35591E-10
0.31281157  3.34354E-10
0.312004    3.33491E-10
0.31102326  3.32443E-10
0.30771822  3.2891E-10
0.30560062  3.26647E-10
0.30413213  3.25077E-10
0.30373717  3.24655E-10
0.29636685  3.16777E-10
0.29622422  3.16625E-10
0.29590765  3.16286E-10
0.2949896   3.15305E-10
0.29414582  3.14403E-10
0.28841901  3.08282E-10
0.28820667  3.08055E-10
0.28291832  3.02403E-10
0.28243792  3.01889E-10
0.28156429  3.00955E-10
0.28043638  2.9975E-10
0.27872239  2.97918E-10
0.27833349  2.97502E-10
0.27825573  2.97419E-10
0.27669023  2.95746E-10
0.27645657  2.95496E-10
```

Expected output text file:

```
0.314611284 3.36278E-10
0.296772974 3.172112E-10
0.279535036 2.987864E-10
```

I tried this code, but i don't know how to include the loop for each 10th row:

```
awk '{x+=$1;next}END{print x/NR}' file
```

Comment: `awk` is a better tool for this kind of task as it involves managing floating-point numbers from a text file. Also it is always a good idea to show your own attempts at solving the problem to get help, because S.O. is not a coding service where one publish code specs and get back working code to solve your problem. Here you describe a problem that could be solved with code, but you need to describe **a problem you have with writing your own code** that you designed to solve a problem.

Comment: While Léa Gris suggests `awk`, I'd suggest Python, as it's built to do this kind of number crunching. Bash, like any shell scripting language, is intended to launch other programs, not run arbitrary statistical operations.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235981/how-to-read-every-ten-lines-of-file-using-awk-in-loop which seems close to what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk` to do this:

```
awk -v m=10 -v OFS="\t" '
FNR%m==1{sum1=0;sum2=0}
{sum1+=$1;sum2+=$2}
FNR%m==0{print sum1/m,sum2/m; lfnr=FNR; next}
END{print sum1/(FNR-lfnr),sum2/(FNR-lfnr)}' file
```

Prints:

```
0.314611    3.36278e-10
0.296773    3.17211e-10
0.279535    2.98786e-10
```

Or if you want the same number of decimals you have, you can use `printf`:

```
awk -v m=10 -v OFS="\t" '
FNR%m==1{sum1=0;sum2=0}
{sum1+=$1;sum2+=$2}
FNR%m==0{printf("%0.9G%s%0.9G\n",sum1/m,OFS,sum2/m); lfnr=FNR; next}
END{printf("%0.9G%s%0.9G\n",sum1/(FNR-lfnr),OFS,sum2/(FNR-lfnr))}' file
```

Prints:

```
0.314611284 3.36278E-10
0.296772974 3.172112E-10
0.279535036 2.98786444E-10
```

Your *superpower* here is the `%` [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) which allows you to detect ever `m` step -- in this case every 10th. Your *x-ray vision* is the `FNR` awk special variable which is the line of the file you are reading.

`FNR%10` is always less than 10 and when `0` you are on the 10th iteration and time to print. When `1` you are on the first iteration and it is time to reset the sums.